# Show multiple graph in one grid from multiple .m files

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to show the result of the first .m file (graph) at the same grid of the graph resulted from another .m file?
I don't want subplot function, I want the two graphs on the same grid (Same origin 0)

Comment: Yes, call `hold on` after you plot your first plot and all additional plots will appear on the same `axes`. Be sure to *not* open a new figure between plots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MATLAB - Multiple plots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772947/matlab-multiple-plots)